# Is it possible to let Orika use an object builder? (Protocol buffers objects)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, orika, protobuf-java

I'm using protocol buffers, which has a builder.

while setting in orika the following:

```
 mapperFactory.classMap(TestMSGA.class, TestMSGB.class)
                .byDefault()
                .register();
```

I'm unable to map the objects, some validation on the object creation.

Is it possible to let orika know to user `TestMSA.newbuilder().build()` when creating the object?